# Необходимо в APACHE указать другой robot.txt

Tags: redirect, apache2, robots.txt

*Robot.txt* зашит в код `hybris`. Есть необходимость, не меняя кода, сделать пересылку запросов *site.dom/robot.txt*, приходящих на `apache`, на локальный файл */home/apache/robot.txt*
Что то вот такого плана:

```
Alias /robots.txt /home/apache/robot.txt
```

Comment: `RewriteRule` c `htaccess` вам помогут

Comment: Сделал `код` ProxyPass /robots.txt !
                   Alias /robots.txt /home/hybris/robots/robots.txt

                 <Directory /home/hybris/robots/*>
                           AllowOverride All
                             Allow from all
                               Require all granted
                 </Directory>  `код`

Comment: Сейчас возникает ошибка You don't have permission to access /robots.txt on this server.

Comment: Не было у апача доступа к файлу. Заработало.